# How do I politely and concisely ask for an external reference? And how long should I wait on a non-response before moving on?

Tags: etiquette

For two fellowship applications, I need to ask an external referee, so an academic I don't know or don't know well, to independently evaluate my research proposal and background. I'm working on designing an e-mail to this effect, and was wondering if anyone had any thoughts or suggestions on the below? Secondly, how long should I wait with no response before asking someone else? (First deadline is Aug. 13.)

Thanks!

---

Dear Dr. X,

My  name is X -- I'm a PhD candidate in X at X where my research focuses on [insert 10 words or so]. I hope this message finds you well.

I'm in the process of developing two fellowship applications (X and X) that would allow me to work with X at the University of X on a project related to [insert 10 words or so]. I'm writing to ask whether you might  consider writing a reference letter as an arm's-length referee (i.e., no  professional affiliation with applicant or proposed supervisor) as part of these two applications. With some slight variation, referees are asked to evaluate the applicant's [lists couple things]. Accordingly, with some minor changes, the same letter could  be used for both applications.

I  would be thrilled to have your participation as a referee not least because of your long-standing expertise in and contributions to my current and proposed areas of research. From [article name] to [article name], your work has helped inform my understanding of issues integral to my emerging research agenda such as [X, X, and X]. For that reason, I believe that you may be especially well-placed to comment on the potential contributions of my proposed study and my research background broadly. Simply for your reference, the deadlines for these letters are X and X.

If this might be something you’re available and open to take on right now, I would be delighted to send you my research proposal and CV for your further consideration.

Thank you very much for your time,